# Play! Need of Flash for input field

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play 1.2.5. In the below statement (got it in Docs):

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="${flash.name}" />
```

what is the use/need of `value` input text parameter and what does `${flash.name}` means for the value field?

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value will be the "default" value or the value to be filled on the page load (for a good example when the users inputs invalid data and you want to show or leave what he has already placed in that field, or to have text fields already filled for the user). More info here: [site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)

the `flash.name` flash is a "container" of key\value pairs that are received on the request by cookie and set by you previously, it works like session but only last for one request. You can find more info here: [site](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#session)